# How to solve a RLC circuit with a dependent current source

Tags: passive-networks

I am working on the following RLC circuit in the drawing.
[image]

I am stuck at the part where the switch goes to 'b'. That's where the dependent source comes to play. Should I use nodal analysis or find the Thevenin equivalent circuit?

Comment: Note that 24/5 V is an initial condition. Nodal analysis is probably easiest.

Comment: So I don't consider the voltage drop across L and C to be 24/5 V right?

Comment: The 24/5 V is across C and L, but it's an initial condition, not a fixed voltage or step. Let this voltage be \$\small v(t)\$, say, then derive the differential equation, and then apply the initial condition. Alternatively, use the Laplace transform if you don't want to do differential equations, but I think that differential equation analysis is better for this problem (which I haven't solved, btw)

Comment: Right! I wanted to go straight into the differential equations bit, but the dependent source was just confusing.